# Setting the lineWidth of a UIBezierPath not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw a circle but the circle border always the same thin no matter what value I set.
It feel like the line with always the default thinnest width.

```
- (void)drawCircleAtPoint:(CGPoint)center radius: (CGFloat)radius{

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    path.lineWidth = 4; // Here
    path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    path.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;

    CGFloat r = radius;


    [path addArcWithCenter:center radius:r startAngle:0.0 endAngle:M_PI*2 clockwise:true];

    [path stroke];

    CAShapeLayer* layer = [CAShapeLayer new];
    layer.path = path.CGPath;
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor.CGColor;
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.yellowColor.CGColor;

    [layer addAnimation:[self getAnimation] forKey:nil];
    [self.layer addSublayer:layer];

}


- (CABasicAnimation*)getAnimation {

    CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.duration = 1.2;
    animation.fromValue = @0;
    animation.toValue = @1;
    return animation;

}
```

This really drove me crazy.

Comment: It always strikes me as super-weird that you set the line width *in the layer*, not in the bezier path!

Comment: Worth noting that the same applies to endcap shape, etc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to change the width of CAShapeLayer and not UIBezierPath. Like this :

```
- (void)drawCircleAtPoint:(CGPoint)center radius: (CGFloat)radius{
    CGFloat r = radius;
    
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path addArcWithCenter:center radius:r startAngle:0.0 endAngle:M_PI*2 clockwise:true];
    [path setLineWidth:4]; // No need
    [path setLineCapStyle:kCGLineCapRound];
    [path setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinRound];
    [path stroke];
    
    CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer new];
    layer.lineWidth = 4; // Add it here 
    layer.path = path.CGPath;
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor.CGColor;
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.yellowColor.CGColor;
    
    [layer addAnimation:[self getAnimation] forKey:nil];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
}
```

Comment: What the role of `path.lineWidth`?

Comment: @JsW I never tried that so I have no Idea about it. Apple docs : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624349-linewidth

Says : The line width defines the thickness of the receiver's stroked path.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. Thanks anyway.